# $x \in A^\prime \iff \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \ \exists x_n \in A$ s.t $0 < \| x -x_n \| < \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I am given the following theorem and proof, but I am unsure about one part of the proof and would really appreciate it if somebody can show and explain the one step to me.

> **Theorem:**
>
> $x \in A^\prime \iff \forall n \in \mathbb{N}  \ \exists x_n \in A$ s.t $0 < \| x -x_n \| < \frac{1}{n}$.

**Proof:**

$\Rightarrow:$

Suppose $x \in A^\prime$ then $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, $B'(x,\frac{1}{n})\cap A\neq \emptyset$.

Consequently, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}\  \exists \ x_n \in B'(x,\frac{1}{n}) \implies \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \ \exists \ x_n \in A $ with $x_n \in B'(x,\frac{1}{n})$. This implies that for each $n$ there exists an $x_n \in A$ with $0 < || x_n -x|| < \frac{1}{n}$.

$\Leftarrow:$

We are given that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists an $x_n \in A$ with $0 < \| x_n -x\| < \frac{1}{n}$ or we are given that for each $n$ there exists a $x_n \in A$ with $x_n \in B'(x,\frac{1}{n})$, or we are given that for each $n$ there exists a $x_n \in B'(x,\frac{1}{n})\cap A$. Hence for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $B'(x,\frac{1}{n})\cap A \neq \emptyset$. From this we show that $x \in A^\prime$.

We must show that for each $r >0, B'(x,r) \cap A \neq \emptyset$. Choose any $r >0$.

We must now find the connection between $r$ and some $\frac{1}{n}$.

> *Choose $n_0$ suth that $\frac{1}{n_0} < r$.*
>
> **(CAN SOMEONE PLEASE SHOW ME HOW/WHY THIS IS POSSIBLE)**
>
> I have a feeling it might have something to do with Archimedian Property, but I am not sure how to show it.

We are given that $B'(x,\frac{1}{n_0})\cap A \neq \emptyset$ thus $B'(x,r)\cap A \neq \emptyset$ because $B'(x,\frac{1}{n_0}) \subset B'(x,r)$.

Comment: Archimedian Property says that given any real number there is a natural number which is greater than the given number. Use this for the real number $\frac{1}{r}.$ So you will get a natural number $n_0$ such that $\frac{1}{r} < n_0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can take $n_0= \lfloor \frac{1}{r}\rfloor+1$ or if you want to use the Archimedien propriety which states: for all real number $x$ there exist an integer $N$ such that $x<N$, and you can use it for $x=\frac{1}{R}$